# how does locking in sqlite work?

Tags: sqlite, lua

**Background Information**

I'm trying to get a better handle on how locking in sqlite works. 
Right now, I'm running a lua script that is attempting to add 200,000 records to a table. 
I'm doing something like this:

```
luasql = require("luasql.sqlite3")
local env = assert(luasql.sqlite3())
local conn = env:connect("widgets.db")
for i = 10000 , 250000, 1 do
        local sql = "insert into test values("..i..","..i..",'widget','test description')"
        print(sql)
        conn:execute(sql)
end
conn:close()
```

The script seems to be taking a long time... in that it's adding a record or two each second. 
Not too too fast. But that's not the question / issue I have.

**Problem**
While this script is running, I just tried to launch another application that also attempts to read from the same database, same widgets table. 
But its failing with an error that the database is locked.

**Question**
While the database is being updated, should I be able to read from it from other processes / applications?

I've been searching on stackoverflow for similar posts but haven't found anything that directly answers my question.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: [File Locking And Concurrency In SQLite Version 3](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html), [Write-Ahead Logging](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html)

Comment: @CL Interesting!  Thanks.  So it sounds like I need to specify PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL; when I connect.  Is that correct?

Comment: @dot Only if you want to use WAL mode (note that CL posted two links). Also, the reason it's inserting so slowly is because you aren't using transactions; see http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q19

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo thanks.  I just tried a test and it did run a lot faster.  Someone else suggested writing everything in to a csv file... and then running sqlite import command to import the table values.